# Leer archivo .xlsx Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, excel, xamarin.forms

Necesito leer los datos de un archivo .xlsx que haya seleccionado el usuario, del cual obtengo la ruta (Ruta de la cual no tengo problema), la forma que encontré es utilizando la librería de Nuget "Documentformat.openxml" [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). He intentado con este código:

```
 public void ReadExcelFile(string fileName)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
            string text;
            foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
                text = "";
                foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    text += c.CellValue.Text + ", ";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero **sólo da los números que hay en las celdas, no el texto**, si por ejemplo en una celda está escrito **"hola123"** me regresa solamente **"123"** **¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?** Si hay alguna otra forma de leer el archivo en Xamarin.Forms con alguna otra librería no tengo problema en realizarlo de esa forma.

Comment: Primero comprueba que formato tienen las celdas que estas capturando en excel (boton derecho-Formato de Celdas). Seguramente tienen formato "General". Prueba a forzar toda la columna a Formato Texto

Answer (score 0):

Si haciendo la comprobación que te indico en el comentario tampoco obtienes los resultados esperados, usa este código:

```
public void ReadExcelFile(string fileName)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
        SharedStringTable sharedStringTable = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
        string text;
        foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
        {
            text = "";
            foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if (c.DataType != null && c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                {
                    text += sharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText)).InnerText + ", ";
                }
                else
                {
                    text += c.CellValue.Text + ", ";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```